# How do I make user input not a string or input but an operator?

Tags: python, user-input

I was trying to make a quick little user-input calculator but to do that I need the user to decide what operator to use. I tried to make the user-input for the operator a string but that obviously didn't work.
I tried it as an integer too but still had no luck. So I'm confused about what it is that I'm supposed to do.

so far I only have this and it shows an error:

```py
num1 = int(input("What is your first number?: "))
num2 = int(input("What is your second number?: "))
op = (input("Enter an operator: ")
print(num1 + op + num2)
```

**SOLVED**

Comment: You can create a mapping which maps the operator to the corresponding function. ie, `op_to_func_map = {'+': operator.add}..'` and later you can lookup the function using the `op` and pass `num1` and `num2` as arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest safe way to do this is by storing the operators as functions in a dictionary:

```
from operator import *
num1 = int(input("What is your first number?: "))
num2 = int(input("What is your second number?: "))
op = input("Enter an operator: ")

ops = {
    "+": add, # from the operators module
    "-": sub,
    "/": div,
    "*": mul
}
      
print(ops[op](num1,num2))
```

Comment: Also make sure to add an extra check to see if `op` is in `ops` or else it will raise `KeyError` for non-existing operator.

Answer (score 0):

you could create some if statements like this:

```
if op == '+':
    print(num1 + num2)
if op == '-':
    print(num1 - num2)
```

Just do the same thing for multiplying and dividing

Comment: yea I just did something like that but instead, I just used a bunch of elif statements.